# convert timestamp to date in java via soap webservice

Tags: java, date, soap, timestamp, converters

How is converted timestamp to date in java.i have get the count value from following code.

this is my code:

```
public class TodayQ {
  public int data() {
    int count=0;

//count++;

try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pro",
                                                   "root", "");

      PreparedStatement statement =
        con.prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND date=CURDATE()");
      ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
      while (result.next()) {
        // Do something with the row returned.
        count++; //if the first col is a count.
      }
    } catch (Exception exc) {
      System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }

    return count;
  }
}
```

This is another class:

```
public class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TodayQ obj = new TodayQ();
    System.out.println(obj.data());
  }
}
```

In my database have date field.here i have save the date is yyyy-mm-dd format means above code is successfully worked and display count value on my console.but i ll change date is timestamp format after i ll run the application means it is not display count value.why this error is occurred here.please explain me.
Here the db name is pro.table name is orders.the field name is date(1343469690,1343470540,1343470556),status(Q,C,P).Here the check the matched query and get the count value is displayed.how is to do.

Comment: What does this have to do with SOAP / WebServices?

Comment: in my database have following 2 fiels.date(1343469690,1343470540,1343470556),status(Q,C,P).here convert timestamp value to date(yyyy-mm-dd) format.after check the query..if the above query is match means count the match the value and display that total count value.

Comment: Here in my database have timestamp value...now the timestamp value  is store in date format.then only i will check the above query.because my database format is timestamp.but the query is date format.

Comment: I still don't understand what your question is. java.sql.Timestamp inherits from java.util.Date so it IS a Date. But I'm not sure that is your question either.

Comment: in my database have date field.here i have save the date is yyyy-mm-dd format means above code is successfully worked and display count value on my console.but i ll change date is timestamp format after i ll run the application means it is not display count value.